# How to save a reconstructed binary image using skimage imsave

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, scikit-image

I have been trying to preprocess an image for feature extraction using skimage library.But I can't save the image as it gives error saying "cannot write mode F as PNG"

the funtion for processing the image is given here

```
def image_process(image):
    img = imread(image)
    rem_img = remove(img)
    rgb_img = rgba2rgb(rem_img)
    gray_img = rgb2gray(rgb_img)
    bin_img = gray_img < threshold_otsu(gray_img)
    smooth_img = gaussian(bin_img)

    seed_px = np.copy(smooth_img)
    seed_px[1:-1 , 1:-1]=smooth_img.max()
    mask = smooth_img
    filled_img = reconstruction(seed_px , mask , method ='erosion')

    return filled_img
```

then just tried to save the image in directory BW uisng imsave

```
leaf_img = "neem.jpg"
processed_img = image_process(leaf_img)
imsave("BW/leaf.png", processed_img)
```

It shows error

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File C:\Python\lib\site-packages\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py:1299, in _save(im, fp, filename, chunk, save_all)
   1298 try:
-> 1299     rawmode, mode = _OUTMODES[mode]
   1300 except KeyError as e:

KeyError: 'F'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[26], line 3
      1 leaf_img = "neem.jpg"
      2 processed_img = image_process(leaf_img)
----> 3 imsave("BW/leaf.png", processed_img)

File C:\Python\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\_io.py:143, in imsave(fname, arr, plugin, check_contrast, **plugin_args)
    141 if check_contrast and is_low_contrast(arr):
    142     warn(f'{fname} is a low contrast image')
--> 143 return call_plugin('imsave', fname, arr, plugin=plugin, **plugin_args)

File C:\Python\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\manage_plugins.py:205, in call_plugin(kind, *args, **kwargs)
    202     except IndexError:
    203         raise RuntimeError(f'Could not find the plugin "{plugin}" for {kind}.')
--> 205 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File C:\Python\lib\site-packages\imageio\v3.py:139, in imwrite(uri, image, plugin, extension, format_hint, **kwargs)
    104 def imwrite(uri, image, *, plugin=None, extension=None, format_hint=None, **kwargs):
    105     """Write an ndimage to the given URI.
    106 
    107     The exact behavior depends on the file type and plugin used. To learn about
   (...)
    136 
    137     """
--> 139     with imopen(
    140         uri,
    141         "w",
    142         legacy_mode=False,
    143         plugin=plugin,
    144         format_hint=format_hint,
    145         extension=extension,
    146     ) as img_file:
    147         encoded = img_file.write(image, **kwargs)
    149     return encoded

File C:\Python\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\v3_plugin_api.py:367, in PluginV3.__exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
    366 def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback) -> None:
--> 367     self.close()

File C:\Python\lib\site-packages\imageio\plugins\pillow.py:123, in PillowPlugin.close(self)
    122 def close(self) -> None:
--> 123     self._flush_writer()
    125     if self._image:
    126         self._image.close()

File C:\Python\lib\site-packages\imageio\plugins\pillow.py:457, in PillowPlugin._flush_writer(self)
    454     self.save_args["save_all"] = True
    455     self.save_args["append_images"] = self.images_to_write
--> 457 primary_image.save(self._request.get_file(), **self.save_args)
    458 self.images_to_write.clear()
    459 self.save_args.clear()

File C:\Python\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py:2431, in Image.save(self, fp, format, **params)
   2428         fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
   2430 try:
-> 2431     save_handler(self, fp, filename)
   2432 except Exception:
   2433     if open_fp:

File C:\Python\lib\site-packages\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py:1302, in _save(im, fp, filename, chunk, save_all)
   1300 except KeyError as e:
   1301     msg = f"cannot write mode {mode} as PNG"
-> 1302     raise OSError(msg) from e
   1304 #
   1305 # write minimal PNG file
   1307 fp.write(_MAGIC)

OSError: cannot write mode F as PNG type here
```

Can someone please explain what is the problem here? and a solution will be really helpful..Thanks in advance